# Are we supposed to say "go..." when parting from the dead?

Tags: funeral-burial-levaya, speech-talking, tractate-brachot

The g'mara on B'rachot 64a quotes R. Avin Halevi as saying that when we depart from a person we should say "go *to* peace" (like Yitro to Moshe), not "go *in* peace" (like David to Avshalom), but that when we depart from the dead we say "go *in* peace" (based on Psalm 84).  A note in my Soncino translation says that this departure from the dead refers to leaving the funeral procession.

I've never learned that I'm supposed to say anything to the meit (dead person) at this point.  I'm not part of my local chevra kadisha, so I don't know if any non-psalm speech is involved, but I had thought not.  (And anyway, that would be earlier than the note suggests.)

Are we supposed to, essentially, verbally say goodbye to the meit at the end of the funeral procession?  If not, did we ever?  If not, what is this g'mara referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) (*Hil. [Avel](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e404.htm#3)*, 4:4) presents this custom as *halacha*, and he is followed by many other *rishonim* including the [Rokeach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_Rokeach) (*Hil. Aveilus*, 313), [*Sefer HaAgudah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Suslin) (*B'rachos*, Chapter 9), [*Kol Bo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_Bo) (§ 114), and the [Ramban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) (*Toras HaAdam, Sha'ar HaSof, Inyan HaHotza'ah*).

This custom is also presented by such later authorities as the [*Beit Yosef*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Ephraim_Karo) (YD 376) and, more recently, the [*Mishnah Berurah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah) (110:17).

Comment: Thanks I couldn't seem to find him on Wikipedia. I added them here because they are more unusual sources to quotes so this way people can more easily put them in historical context (rishon/achron ashkenaz/sefardi etc.).

Comment: Fred, I don't see the relevance of your second paragraph to the question, which makes me wonder whether "this" in your first paragraph actually refers to what was asked in the question.

Comment: @msh210 The second para addressed a more general question suggested by the title "Are we supposed to talk to the dead"? Yes, the first paragraph does in fact refer to the specific custom asked about in the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Fred, I've now [fixed](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/20560/revisions) the title, making it more accurately reflect the question.

Comment: Fred, yes IMO, especially if my edit to the question doesn't get reverted, but, really, even if it does, since the question is the body and the title is just a title.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion my header caused.  Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Fred, all these sources do quote the Gemara, but they do so basically word for word. Is there an indication anywhere that Niftar min haMet actually means talking to the deceased or perhaps it means to the mourners, or the pallbearers, or something else.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - No problem at all; I just added in some better known sources, ranging from the Rambam to the Chafetz Chaim.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Not all of these sources do so. E.g. the Kol Bo: ‎ואחרי הקבורה המלוין את המת אומרים לו לך בשלום ונופלין על קברו ונושקין הקבר ועפרו דרך כבוד המת דוגמת מה שאמרו בגמרא מאן יהיב לן מעפריה דרב ושמואל ונמלינהו לעיינין, וכך אמרו עפריה דרב הוו יהבי לאשתא בת יומא

Comment: @DoubleAA - Also the Rambam: 
‎והמלוין אותו אומרין לו לך בשלום שנאמר ואתה תבוא אל אבותיך בשלום

Comment: @Fred Fair enough. That's what I get for only reading some of the sources inside :)