# Proof that calling upon deceased righteous people is polythiesm

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, avodah-zarah

My assumption is that in the Jewish faith, if someone were to call upon a righteous person who is not alive for help, that would be considered polytheism.

Are there any explicit verses in the Torah that say that this is prohibited?

E.g.: Someone cannot get pregnant, or needs help finding a job, so they raise their hands and call upon someone who is not living for help in this matter.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44719

Comment: @msh210 The only difference that i see is that this one asks for for a biblical source.