# What is the source of the custom to pray on graves of Tzadikim?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, cemetery-grave

The Galilee has several such locations where people visit and pray asking for what their heart desires. 
What is the source of this custom?
How does it align with graves being in general a source of inpurity?

EDIT:
Here is a question covering the legitimacy of praying to the dead, [Do Jews pray to deceased forefathers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44719)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Jews pray to deceased forefathers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/do-jews-pray-to-deceased-forefathers)

Comment: @robev there are answers there covering the 'praying to the dead' part of my question. But not the main part of my question. Will edit. Thanks.

Comment: [Kalev is a good source](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.34b.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi).

Answer (score 2):

One source is Rashi quoting Medrash in Bamidbar 13,22

> "ויבא עד חברון" - (סוטה לד) כלב לבדו הלך שם ונשתטח על קברי אבות שלא יהא ניסת לחבריו להיות בעצתם וכן הוא אומר (דברים א) ולו אתן את הארץ אשר דרך בה וכתיב (שופטים א) ויתנו לכלב את חברון
>   Kaleb went to pray by our Forefathers so that he should not be tempted to join the spies bad report of the Land of Israel

Another source is Rashi Bereishis 48,7 that in Yirmiya chapter 31 when the Bnei Yisroel were sent to exile they would pray by Rachel's tomb to help them.

> "ואקברה שם" - ולא הולכתיה אפי' לבית לחם להכניסה לארץ וידעתי שיש בלבך עלי אבל דע לך שע"פ הדבור קברתיה שם שתהא לעזרה לבניה כשיגלה אותם נבוזראדן והיו עוברים דרך שם יצאת רחל על קברה ובוכה ומבקשת עליהם רחמים שנא' (ירמיהו לא) קול ברמה נשמע וגו' והקב"ה משיבה יש שכר לפעולתך נאם ה' וגו' ושבו בנים לגבולם