# Does Chinese ancestor worship have the full status of idolotry?

Tags: halacha, death, avodah-zarah, family-members, issurei-hanaa

In the front of a Chinese restaurant they have a small shrine - a succah less than a foot tall. Placed before it is a bowl of rice with vertical chopsticks and a plate of oranges. There is no idol inside it, rather there is an inscribed tablet. This is a method of sending provisions to an ancestor rather than paying homage to a god.

Do the items have the same prohibitions of a equivalent items snatched from an altar to Baal Peor?

Comment: I remember the same question in m.y.

Comment: Cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44719/170

Comment: Sending provisions - is it to somewhat 'nourish' their ancestor, or more like a gift/homage/worship ? This could make a big difference.

Answer (score 4):

R. Ethan Tucker discusses a very similar issue -- whether one can "salute the ancestors" at a karate class -- in the below podcast.  He concludes that much depends on the intent of the person who put up the photo/shrine, and whether the salute is understood as a form of real worship or a customary mark of respect.

http://jpmedia.co/can-i-bow-down-during-karate-class/

Comment: Avi K, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for sharing this source! You could make this answer even more valuable by [edit]ing it to add a bit more out your summary of the relevant parts of the podcast and how they relate to the question at hand. I hope to see you around!