# לך לשלום vs לך עם שלום vs לך בשלום

Tags: words, tractate-brachot, shalom-peace

On page Berachos 33a<sup>1</sup> the story of the Pious man praying on the road & the General, towards the end of the story it is stated that the "General was appeased and the Pious man departed to his home "IN PEACE."

We learned later in Berachos 64a<sup>2</sup> in the "fourth teaching from R'Avin the Levi" the proper way to part from friends. Which is to "Go to peace" vs "Go with peace." Is the term to go "in peace" ever expounded upon in the talmud?

**צום מועיל**

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya! I went ahead and formatted the superscripts for you; you use the HTML tags to do it, `<sup>insert superscript here</sup>`. (I assume you're referring to the pagination in Artscroll?) I'm not clear on your question here; isn't לך בשלום addressed in that same Gemara in the context of Avshalom, in contrast to Yisro's לך לשלום?

Comment: Thank you, and it is a pleasure to be here. In the Daf Yomi Size Schottenstein Edition, the translation reads that the Pious man went in peace, but the actual Hebrew/Aramaic text reads לך לשלום. I guess it would be a question to ask the commentator why they chose to write in peace.

Comment: https://mefo.otzar.org/#/t/21554/b/173917/p/72/s/127863 brings from pele yoets that he did die straight away.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20560