# Is there a formal Jewish way of wishing someone a safe journey?

Tags: minhag, blessing, travel, tefilat-haderech

Before someone you know goes on a trip, such as a flight, it is polite to wish them a safe journey. In English, one might use some variation of "safe travels" or "have a safe trip". In Judaism, a person recites [Tefilat HaDerech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefilat_HaDerech) for his or herself, a prayer for a safe journey.

Is there a formal or traditional farewell (perhaps a bracha) that one can give to someone before they leave on a trip?

Comment: צאתכם לשלום *Go towards peace* note that the usage of the lamed rather than the bais.  Whan someone uses the bais, it implies wishing the person a peaceful death as in the English *Rest in peace*

Comment: @sabbahillel https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.29a.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: לחיים ולשלום (15 char)

Comment: I've heard "Derech Tzleicha", may you have a successful route, don't know if it's only Hebrew or Jewish too

Comment: @sabbahillel Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20560

Comment: ?נסיעה טובה or is that modern?

Answer (score 1):

There is a minhag to give someone 'shlichus mitzva gelt' to give to tzedakka when they arrive in their destination. This comes from the chazal 'Shluchay mitzvah eino nezakin', someone who is a messenger to do a mitzvah will not come to harm.

Answer (score 0):

Since it says הנפרד מחברו יפרד ממנו מתוך דבר הלכה, the [Ben Ish Chai - Parshas Eikev 18](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=204) says that one who is going to travel you should say י'חיד ו'רבים ה'לכה כ'רבים

> ויכוין ראשי תיבות שם יוה"כ המסוגל לשמירת הדרך שרמוז זה בסופי תיבות כ'י
> מלאכי'ו יצו'ה ל'ך